# Pandas - Changing order of multiple-headers in Panda Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, slice, multi-index

I have a pandas dataframe with index of column=0 and two header rows, that look like this

```
1     2     3     4
Grid Year  Lat   Lon
_________________________
1  2002  51.52  -0.12
2  2003  51.52  -0.12
```

I would like to change the order of the two header columns, into

```
Grid Year  Lat   Lon
1     2     3     4
__________________________
1  2002  51.52  -0.12
2  2003  51.52  -0.12
```

Does anyone have tips on solutions? I tried finding a good solution online but none has given me any clues in how to succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming this is your dataframe,

```
print(df)

     1     2      3      4 <-- multi index
  Grid  Year    Lat    Lon <-- multi index
1    1  2002  51.52  -0.12
2    2  2003  51.52  -0.12
```

we can swap the levels using the handy `.swaplevel` method.

read more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html)

```
df.columns = df.columns.swaplevel(0)
#or 
#df.columns = df.swaplevel(0,axis=1)

  Grid  Year    Lat    Lon
     1     2      3      4
1    1  2002  51.52  -0.12
2    2  2003  51.52  -0.12
```

Comment: Yes thank you, it worked perfectly. My dataframe is though as I stated above from reading it into python using read_csv( index_col = 0), so i do not have the extra index column that are in your solution. But still, it worked great with that as well!

Comment: @gusbacos ah, try `pd.read_csv(file,header=[0,1])` :)